# How to upload file in database in MongoDB using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using Node-Express and mongoose for database application. I want to upload a file in database. So the clear idea is that when any user upload a photo or doc or any of the file it should be inserted into database the whole file. I try to find on web a lot about this but it doesn't give me any proper answer. Can you tell me the methods available in mongoose to achieve this?

Comment: this may help you [store img in mongo with mongoose](https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/2408370)

Comment: Saving file to db is the bad way, just save file name to your db.

Answer (score 0):

Okay So you need to create an API which take the file and upload it to server.

and you should upload that particular file to the public folder where you can serve that ,

And in that API you should return the url of that particular file , and then you can save the `url` of that file in your `db`

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html